# How to load image in android webview?

Tags: android, html, image, webview

I can not show a image in android  webview    use method loadUrl("http://www.zhihu.com/question/22091564/answer/25190954");

maybe the js or css  is not load。 i can‘t solve it 。

like：

```
<img src="//s1.zhimg.com/misc/whitedot.jpg" data-rawwidth="1132" data-rawheight="659" class="origin_image zh-lightbox-thumb lazy" width="1132" data-original="http://p1.zhimg.com/85/dd/85dd508328e80af323a98e1d8e05db6a_r.jpg" data-actualsrc="http://p1.zhimg.com/85/dd/85dd508328e80af323a98e1d8e05db6a_m.jpg">
```

link：http://www.zhihu.com/question/22091564/answer/25190954

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public class YourActivity extends Activity {

private static final String HTML_FORMAT = "<html><body style=\"text-align: center; background-color: black; vertical-align: center;\"><img src = \"%s\" /></body></html>";
private WebView mWebView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.yourWebView);

    final String imgUrl = "http://xxx.xxx";
    final String html = String.format(HTML_FORMAT, imgUrl);

    mWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL("", html, "text/html", "UTF-8", "");
    //not required but cant help
    mWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(false); 
    }
}
```

Comment: i think the js not load。

Comment: Add this:

mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

Comment: have " mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true) " , but not working

Comment: could you show image useing  this url " http://www.zhihu.com/question/22091564/answer/25190954 "?